# Flutter build apk on release mode cannot generate updated version

Tags: android, flutter, dart, release-apk

I had run this  `flutter build apk` to release my App. Now I had built version 2 of that.

Now, I want to release my version 2 App. So, I run `flutter build apk` again. I get the released apk but It is still version 1 released apk.
I deleted the released apk and tried again but still got version 1 released apk.

[image: I tried this too but It is also giving me Version 1 apk]

While building version 2 in debug mode, everything works fine.

Here is the Github Link to that App: https://github.com/nitishk72/Flutter-Github-API

Answer (score 79, accepted):

I think you need

```
flutter clean
```

(I'd consider it a bug that this is necessary, but I'm encountering it as well)

and

```
flutter build apk --release
```

Comment: Glad to hear . .

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I am still facing the problem. it says that

`
Running 'gradlew assembleRelease'...
Dart snapshot generator failed with exit code -1073741819
Snapshotting exited with non-zero exit code: -1073741819
`
I feel uncomforttable to give a debuggable version.

Comment: I also don't think shipping a debug version is a good idea (if even possible) but I don't know how to solve. Can you please create an issue in GitHub with as much information as possible.

Comment: It's not working for me. PLease help. When opened the app gets killed.

Answer (score 100):

If your problem is that the ***flutter build*** (APK, bundle) isn't making API calls in a real device, this is because ***you need to add the Internet permission to Android Manifest*** before creating the release/build.

By default, "internet use" will work fine on the emulator but not on a real device.

To fix this, simply:

Open the file "android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" and add the proper user-permission:

```
<manifest> 
...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
...
</manifest>
```

And then create your build again.

Comment: Thanks! This is a bit confusing, but makes sense since Flutter debug version always needs internet permission in order to use debugging tools. A discussion about this is here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20789

Comment: Thank you so much! I couldn't how should I frame my question on google but here is the answer! You saved my day!

Answer (score 34):

I had facing same problem "Application work properly in Debug mode but not in release mode". I don't know why... but finally, I have solved by adding these lines `shrinkResources false minifyEnabled false` in android/app/build.gradle file.

```
 buildTypes {
     release {
         signingConfig signingConfigs.config
         shrinkResources false
         minifyEnabled false
     }
 }
```

Comment: For some reasons, the --no-shrink build parameter stopped working for me, but this helped

Comment: Isn't shrinking file size and obfuscating the code important?

Answer (score 10):

When you are creating new Flutter project (from Android Studio menu), in file:

```
/android/app/build.gradle
```

which is there:
[image]

you have:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug    //   <--- HERE YOU ARE USING DEBUG KEY
    }
}
```

Which means that `release` build (e.g. triggered from menu `Build -> Flutter -> Build APK`)  will use `debug` key for signing.

Full `build.gradle` file (created by Android Studio):
[image]

## Solution

Change from:

```
signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
```

to:

```
signingConfig signingConfigs.release
```

so (in `build.gradle`) you should have:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

## Error

When you have error `Could not get unknown property 'release' for SigningConfig` - just add section `release` in `build.gradle`, so:

1. Create new `.jks` file (via `Generate Signed Bundle / APK...`
2. Put credentials in `build.gradle (:app)`:

   [image: enter code here]

Comment: It doesn`t work to me, got the error: Could not get unknown property 'release' for SigningConfig container of type org.gradle.api.internal.FactoryNamedDomainObjectContainer.

Comment: @MarcoA.Braghim the error is so so clear. You do not have `property 'release'` in `SigningConfig container`. In `android { }` you have to create it, so `android { signingConfigs { release { } } }` and ther put your `keyAlias`,  `storeFile`, `keyPassword` and `storePassword`.

Answer (score 8):

1. you can change in local.properties android project

   ```
       sdk.dir=D:/SDK               //your android SDK location
       flutter.sdk=D:\\Flutter\\flutter  //your flutter SDK location
       flutter.versionName=1.0.0
       flutter.versionCode=2
       flutter.buildMode=release
   ```
2. changes in your android/app/build.gradle file

   ```
        buildTypes {
               release {
                   // if everything ok then not add 
                   //minifyEnabled true 
                   //another you can remove minifyEnabled true
                   proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard- 
                    android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                   signingConfig signingConfigs.release
               }
           }
   ```
3. you can also changes in android/app/build.gradle defaultConfig method 
   body.

   ```
     multiDexEnabled true
   ```
4. if you want to migrate to androidx then do it setup.

   dependencies {
       testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
       androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
       androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
       implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'

   }

   5. and clean before create build folder by following this cmd.

      ```
       - flutter clean

       - flutter build apk --release

       - flutter install
      ```

6.Release Apk location.

```
        in `android studio termial` or inside `project-root` you can navigate to this.

        cd build\app\outputs\apk\release
```

Comment: iOS dev here. Did Android using Flutter.

Tried flutter clean and then flutter apk --release but it always created a debug build.

Followed above steps and added signingConfig.release and got the Release build with flutter apk -- release

also refer https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android which is essentially above stuff but in detail on how to create the key file and where to store and link it, etc.

Comment: it will create debugRelease. ( why because inside app folder inside android code , you will find a build.gradle where you will see release tag which is bind default to debug.keystore.

Comment: oh. Then how do I create a Release build?

Comment: you can create release build from Android-studio. there is a option present.

Comment: Thanks Tushar. I was getting some weird error on Android Studio.
So I created the release build from command line (flutter apk --release).

Answer (score 7):

## If you're using an API Call#

Make sure you have the **Internet Permission** on you android Manifest

```
<manifest> 
...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
...
</manifest>
```

## If you're using Shared Preferences plugin

In **`android\build.gradle`** set your dependencies to use the **`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'`**

**NOT** **`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0`**

Like this:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

#### 1).

add following lines in `android\app\src\mainAndroid manifest`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

and then add these lines in `android\app\build.gradle`

```
   buildTypes {
   release {
        shrinkResources false
        minifyEnabled false
   }}
```

#### 2).

Building `apk` using the below commands.

`flutter build apk --no-shrink`

or

`flutter build apk --split-per-abi --no-shrink`

**Both Solutions worked for me but personally I recommend second one**

Answer (score 4):

I hope this can help someone. I ran into a problem that my release version does not works and there are no any error messages in logcat.
The problem turned out to be that I had `FutureBuilder` in which i start `Future<void>`. By running `flutter run` it works properly (`snapshot.hasData` was `true`), but in release version it was always `false`. Of course, documentation of the `FutureBuilder` says that `hasData` should be `false` in this case. But in fact in debug mode it has different behaviour.

P.S. *Another possible problems:*
Now my app still not working, but this time i saw on logcat next error:

`Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences)`

Downgrading gradle plugin version from 7.* to 3.5.4 solves this issue.

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4'`

Answer (score 2):

I decide to open the MyProject/android folder in android studio and build the apk from android studio.
It finally worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
flutter build apk // this generate apk 

flutter build appbundle // this generate aab
```

And remember that you need to execute `flutter clean` before execute `flutter build apk`