# Flutter: SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

I'm building app using different ways, two works but one fails.

**Method:1 (Working)**

```
flutter build appbundle
```

---

**Method:2 (Working)**

Opening module in Android Studio, after that, choosing

```
Build > Generate Signed Bundle/APK... > filling all info afterwards
```

In this case, I am able to build both app bundle and APK file.

---

**Method:3 (Not working)**

```
flutter build apk
```

I get this error:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>   * What went wrong:
>   A problem occurred configuring root project 'android_intent'.
>
> SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

---

If I remove `android_intent`, I start getting error in other packages, so definitely the package isn't a problem. I double checked that I have

`local.properties`, `gradle.properties` and `settings.gradle` in my `android` root folder.

And my other projects seem to work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter Release apk is not working properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49874194/flutter-release-apk-is-not-working-properly)

Comment: @MidhunMP I tried that, it didn't work.

Answer (score 15):

I have faced  this issue with **file_picker** plugin, Just upgrade  gradle version in android/build.gradle to one of these versions :

```
3.3.3

3.4.3

3.5.4

3.6.4

4.0.1
```

I followed this link : [file_picker troubleshooting](https://github.com/miguelpruivo/flutter_file_picker/wiki/Troubleshooting#android)

Comment: I'm already using the latest gradle version `4.1.1`

Comment: Can you post your android/build.gradle  and android/app/build.gradle

Comment: Worked for me, version 3.5.4.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes you will see an SDK problem **from a plugin that requires the latest gradle to actually run**.

**I was running into this even though my SDK was properly set:**

> SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the
> local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

**More info from:**

[Here is an example of a plugin failure that will lead to an sdk and query error **flutter_file_picker**:](https://github.com/miguelpruivo/flutter_file_picker/wiki/Troubleshooting#android)

```
Build is failing with unexpected element <queries> found in <manifest>.
```

**Upgrade gradle:**

To upgrade gradle in a flutter project, **File -> Open** and select the Android folder which is part of your Flutter application. When that finishes loading, it will prompt you to upgrade gradle to the latest version. This will resolve the issue

Comment: Thanks! I had exactly this issue with file picker.

Comment: @Petro Thank you, I'll take a look into it and will accept the answer :)

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: @Petro Sorry I didn't help, I'm already using latest version of gradle, it's `4.1.1`.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.
In my case, an outdated package was the cause of the problem

Answer (score 2):

To fix this issue try to upgrade the Gradle version to the latest version.

For doing this go to `android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` and then, replace the version of `distributionUrl` with the latest Gradel version.

for example:

upgrade:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.2-all.zip
```

to:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-all.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue but there is a file create in

`build\app\outputs\apk\release\app-release.apk`

which when installed works fine without any issue . Even I don't know why this happens but it works.

Comment: The file that is created in the directory you mentioned can only be possible if you already had built a released version. And only you can tell which method you used to do that. I don't understand how your comment like answer answers this post.

Answer (score 1):

So in my case what I feel is happening is that there is a conflict between the new build and the already existing build due to a new package or something else so I did
`flutter clean` and tried building again and voila it worked.

Comment: everyone is not lucky like you.. didn't work for me also..

Answer (score 0):

In `android\gradle.properties` make sure `android.enableR8` is NOT set to `false`. It may just be related to your apk size, not a specific package.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Here how I solved it.

Make sure you have a file called local.properties in android folder, and make sure it has a correct Computer user name such as like that:

```
sdk.dir=C:\\Users\\YOURUSERNAME\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk
flutter.sdk=C:\\src\\flutter
flutter.buildMode=debug
flutter.versionName=1.0.5
flutter.versionCode=10
```

for MAC, path should be like that

```
sdk.dir = /Users/YOURUSERNAME/Library/Android/sdk
```

In case if this doesn't work, add ANDROID_HOME variable in "Environment Variables" as C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

Answer (score -1):

in mac os.
open terminal and run below command

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

type below values in terminal with your user_name

```
export ANDROID_HOME="/Users/<user_name>/Library/Android/sdk"
export ANDROID_TOOLS="/Users/<user_name>/Library/Android/sdk/tools/"
export ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS="/Users/<user_name>/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/"
```

and save them by control+X and then Enter

after that restart terminal and type below command

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

finally type

```
echo $ANDROID_HOME
```

I have to do it on my project folder then it worked for me.