# APIs won't load when published on Google Playstore

Tags: android, flutter, api, dart, google-play

So this is my first time publishing a Flutter app to the Google Play Store.  I wanted to create something simple so I could learn the entire process.  So I created a simple Trivia App.

When I run the app from my phone or emulator (Android or iPhone) the free API that I'm using [here](https://opentdb.com/api_category.php) loads the categories without any issues.

[image: What the app should look like]

The issue I'm having is when I publish the app to the Play Store, the API doesn't load and I don't even get an error message.  Just a blank screen.

[image: App when published to play store]

Here is the API service call in my app:

```
 static Future<List<Category>> fetchCategories() async {
    const url = "https://opentdb.com/api_category.php";
    var response;
    try {
      response = await http.get(url);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var jsonString = response.body;
        final Map<String, dynamic> responseData = json.decode(jsonString);
        var list = responseData['trivia_categories'] as List;
        var _items = list.map((i) => Category.fromJson(i)).toList();
        return _items;
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    } on Exception {
      throw response.statusCode;
    }
  }
```

And this is the code in the controller that calls the API's method.

```
 void fetchCategories() async {
    // flag as loading.
    isLoading(true);
    try {
      //get categories from API server
      var categories = await ApiServices.fetchCategories();
      if (categories != null) {
        categories.forEach((Category categoryItem) async {
          // adjust data accordingly
          categoryItem.totalQuestions =
              await fetchCategoryCount(categoryItem.id);
          if (userDataController.data.read(categoryItem.id.toString()) !=
              null) {
            // get a list of answered questions from the device and count them
            List<dynamic> correctAnswers =
                userDataController.data.read(categoryItem.id.toString());
            categoryItem.correctAnswers = correctAnswers.length;
          } else {
            categoryItem.correctAnswers = 0;
          }
          categoryTiles.add(categoryItem);
        });
      }
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      throw new Exception("An error occured fetching the data");
    } finally {
      isLoading(false);
    }
  }
```

Has anyone else ran into this issue?

Comment: Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/63000042/8174223

Comment: That was it!  Thanks Michael!

Comment: Glad it worked!