# Flutter release app crashes after first screen

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I am working on an app that uses firebase sign. The application is working perfectly on debug mode but when I release it, the application crashes just after the user as successfully login. Since the application is in release mode, there is no way to monitor the logs so as to tell where the error is coming from.

I was using flutter 2.8 from the stable channel but after reading some of the things said on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49874194/flutter-release-apk-is-not-working-properly), I decided to upgrade to the latest version of the stable channel but still, nothing works. I will appreciate help.

- I have clean and pub get
- I have use the "--no-shrink" command

Comment: I am using phone number signin. The application successfully signs in but crashes after moving to the home screen

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed it. I added no shrink command to my build.gradle