# android in release mod loses connection

Tags: android, flutter, server, vds

I migrated my app to remote servers, and changed the ip address in the code from localhost to server address, in the simulator and on physical iOS devices everything works as it should, but when I build the apk for release I see Connection failed in the logs when any request is made to the remote server. Although I repeat on my iOS there is no such thing, only on android, I thought it was the application signature, I signed it, nothing changed either

Comment: I found a solution to my problem here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49874194/flutter-build-apk-on-release-mode-cannot-generate-updated-version